# Python Flask and sqlite3 commit not working

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, commit

This is just a small bite of my code but I hope it will be enough so solve my problem. Allow me to explain first.

So I am attempting to store information in a database using python and sqlite3. I can store stuff in the database but the file size of the database never increases and after a restart the database is cleared. I know that .commit works because I have used it in the past but it is not working now. My assumption is that I am out of scope of the database and I don't have the ability to write. Once again, my code runs and provides no errors, but it will not actually write to the database.

My Connection and Init Code:

```
def connect_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn


def init_db():
    conn = connect_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = 'create table if not exists users (id integer primary key autoincrement, username text not null, password text not null, admin boolean not null)'
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
```

So this code connects to the database and gets everything setup.

Here is a small portion of my code to add an item to the database. It works and it will add items to the "database" but the file size of the database does not increase and if I restart it wont see the new items. But as long as the application is open I have access to the items.

```
@app.route('/user/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def users():
    conn = connect_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    isAdmin = False
    if (request.form.get('adminuser') != None):
        isAdmin = True
    cursor.execute('insert into users (username, password, admin) values (?, ?, ?)',
                 [request.form['username'], request.form['password'], isAdmin])
    conn.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Edit I left This Out

```
DATABASE = '/tmp/database.db'
```

Edit A Crazy Simple Mistake.

Change

```
DATABASE = '/tmp/database.db'
```

To

```
DATABASE = './tmp/database.db'
```

Comment: What is the value `app.config['DATABASE']`?

Comment: Yes I am sorry I left that out. DATABASE = '/tmp/database.db'

Comment: When you remove that file, is it recreated?

Comment: Just tested. It seems that when the file is removed it is not re-created. But I can still create items in a "database" somewhere and access them.

Comment: I just found my solution. I needed to change /tmp/database.db to .'/tmp/database.db

Comment: Sorry, my dupe closing here was in error; tab confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in this line:

```
DATABASE = '/tmp/database.db'
```

Use this instead:

```
DATABASE = './tmp/database.db'
```

Comment: Oh, just realized you found the solution sorry.